# How to avoid the jquery "colorbox" closing when we are submitting the data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, colorbox

i'm calling the external php page by using the ajax method in Jquery colorbox in that while i'm submitting the data the colorbox is closed automatically n go to the normal page view without lightbox how to avoid that and reopen the colorbox after submitting....

Please tell some suggestions r solutions abt this problems friends...
//home page
//jquery of colorbox

```
 <script src="jquery/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $(".ajax").colorbox({width:"63%", height:"80%"})
        });
</script>
<a class="ajax" href="assign_ajax.php">New Task</a>
```

This is the the page called by ajax in colorbox while submitting it goes to the normal page out of colorbox im using 
//////////////////////////////ajax page///////////////////////

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])){ 

$sql = UPDATE `notes` SET `note`=$_POST['update_text'] WHERE`id`={$_GET['note_id']};
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}


<form name="update_form" id="update_form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);>?note_id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" method="post">
<textarea name="update_text" id="update_text" rows="5" cols='55'><?php echo $row['note']; ?></textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" id="update" name="update" value="update">
<input type="button" value="cancel" class ="edit" id="edit-<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
</form>
```

Comment: How do you call external page? using form or? Please post at least part of your code.

Comment: Please post some code. It is nearly impossible to understand all of this in the current state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="jquery/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<script>
    function showColorBox(event)
    {
       event.preventDefault();
       $.colorbox({href:"assign_ajax.php"});
    }
</script>
<a class="ajax" onclick="showColorBox(event)">New Task</a>
//Or
<script src="jquery/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $(".ajax").on("click",function(event){
             event.preventDefault();
             $.colorbox({href:$(this).attr("href")});
        });
    });
</script>
<a class="ajax" href="assign_ajax.php">New Task</a>
```

**EDIT**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['update'])){ 
    $sql = "UPDATE `notes` SET `note`=$_POST['update_text'] WHERE`id`={$_GET['note_id']}";
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
?>


<form name="update_form" id="update_form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);>?" note_id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return FALSE;">
<textarea name="update_text" id="update_text" rows="5" cols='55'><?php echo $row['note']; ?></textarea>
<br>
<input type="button" id="update" name="update" value="update">
<input type="button" value="cancel" class ="edit" id="edit-<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
</form>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#update").on("click",function(){
             $.ajax({url: $("#update_form").attr("action"), data:{note_id: $("#update_form").attr("note_id"),update_text:$("#update_text").val()}, type:"POST", dataType:"json"}).done(function(data){});
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Here am using the button and not the link and in this the post is submitted by the php code i want to reopen that colorbox after executing the SQL statements

Comment: Did you load all the information and display them on the color box?

Comment: s i want to load the information in the colorbox after submitting the data into the database after submitting... at present it is displaying normally without colorbox after submitting

Comment: I think that It's pretty difficult for you. If you want to be help more. Contact me. SkypeID: jewelnguyen8. The code you post here is like a mess.